# configure script cannot find libxml2 on mac

Tags: macos, homebrew, libxml2, configure

when I execute

```
./configure
...
checking for libxml-2.0... no
configure: error: Library libxml2 not found, install library or build without (using --disable-xml).
```

I installed libxml2 with brew and checked a lot of articles, but nothing helped so far.

---

**UPDATE**

```
./configure --help
Some influential environment variables:
  CC          C compiler command
  CFLAGS      C compiler flags
  LDFLAGS     linker flags, e.g. -L<lib dir> if you have libraries in a
              nonstandard directory <lib dir>
  LIBS        libraries to pass to the linker, e.g. -l<library>
  CPPFLAGS    (Objective) C/C++ preprocessor flags, e.g. -I<include dir> if
              you have headers in a nonstandard directory <include dir>
  CPP         C preprocessor
  PKG_CONFIG  path to pkg-config utility
  PKG_CONFIG_PATH
              directories to add to pkg-config's search path
  PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
              path overriding pkg-config's built-in search path
  libxml2_CFLAGS
              C compiler flags for libxml2, overriding pkg-config
  libxml2_LIBS
              linker flags for libxml2, overriding pkg-config
```

Comment: does it work when you pass the location of the lib to the script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**homebrew** installs `libxml2` as *"keg only"* which means it is not symlinked to the normal `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib` directories... which means nothing can find it without help. You can get all the above info by running:

```
brew info libxml2
```

If you run:

```
brew ls libxml2
```

it will tell you the full paths to all the files in that package.

If you also run:

```
./configure --help
```

it should tell you what environment variables you need to set in order to find `libxml2` So, armed with these last two pieces of info, you should be able to work out what you need to set and how.

---

I note there is a `pkg-config` file listed for `libxml2` by **homebrew** at:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.10/lib/pkgconfig/libxml-2.0.pc
```

which is also available via a non-version-specific symlink as:

```
/usr/local/opt/libxml2/lib/pkgconfig/libxml-2.0.pc
```

so, if you have installed `pkg-config` with **homebrew**, like this:

```
brew install pkg-config
```

the solution may be just to add the path for that to your `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` with:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/opt/libxml2/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

and then to rerun your `configure` script.

---

Note: It is only *after* installing `pkg-config` (via `brew`) that **homebrew** will display `pkg-config` related "caveats" for many affected packages e.g. `libffi`:

```
==> Caveats
libffi is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because some formulae require a newer version of libffi.

For compilers to find libffi you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib"

For pkg-config to find libffi you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Unfortunately, however, this appears not to be the case for `libxml2` for some reason. (Related **homebrew** issue: "[libxml2 install path](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/56402#issuecomment-646304592)".)

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: when I try to run it after adding `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`, it doesn't work... will try do something with setting the path, but I was trying something like that before but it didn't work. Btw, I have updated my post.

Comment: Have you installed `pkg-config` with `brew install pkg-config` ?

Comment: okay, I missed that I need to have it installed, now it works! thank you so much

Comment: Excellent :-) Good luck with your project!

Comment: I'll improve my answer and be a bit more explicit about that! Done!